# Saving Canvas to bmp is not saving correct coordinates

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, bmp

I would like to save the contents of MainCanvas as a BMP file.

This is an image of the entire screen. Note that MainCanvas is the white area where the grid is displayed with the woods pattern:

[image]

This is the code for saving the MainCanvas to disk as a BMP:

```
private void SaveMapFileAs_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

            Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog();
            dlg.DefaultExt = ".bmp"; // Default file extension
            dlg.Filter = "BMP files (.bmp)|*.bmp"; // Filter files by extension

            // Show save file dialog box
            Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

            // Process save file dialog box results
            if (result == true)
            {
                string filename = dlg.FileName;
                Rect rect = new Rect(MainCanvas.RenderSize);
                RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)rect.Right,
                  (int)rect.Bottom, 96d, 96d, System.Windows.Media.PixelFormats.Default);
                rtb.Render(MainCanvas);
                //endcode as BMP
                BitmapEncoder bmpEncoder = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
                bmpEncoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(rtb));

                //save to memory stream
                System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

                bmpEncoder.Save(ms);
                ms.Close();
                System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filename, ms.ToArray());

            }

    }
```

This is the result of the save:

[image]

As you can see, it is the correct width and height of MainCanvas but it is not saving from 0,0 of the MainCanvas but rather 0,0 of the entire screen.

Lastly, here is the XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="MapDesignModule.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MapDesignModule"

        WindowState="Maximized" UseLayoutRounding="True" 
        ResizeMode="CanMinimize" 
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" WindowStyle="SingleBorderWindow" Title="Map Design Module" MaxHeight="900" MaxWidth="1440" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" FontFamily="Rudyard WF" FontSize="16">

    <StackPanel>
        <Menu VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Width="1440" Margin="0,0,0,0" FontFamily="Ephinol WF" FontSize="16">
            <Menu.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0.5" StartPoint="0,0.5">
                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.291" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF6F6454" Offset="0.924" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Menu.Background>
            <MenuItem Header="File">
                <MenuItem Header="_New Map" Name="NewMap" />
                <MenuItem Header="_Open Map File..." Name="OpenMapFile" />
                <MenuItem Header="_Save Map File" Name="SaveMapFile" />
                <MenuItem Header="_Save Map File As..." x:Name="SaveMapFileAs" Click="SaveMapFileAs_click" />
                <Separator/>
                <MenuItem Header="_Print Map..." Name="PrintMapMenu" Click="PrintMapMenu_click" />
                <Separator/>
                <MenuItem Header="_Quit to Main Menu"  />
                <MenuItem Header="_Quit to Desktop" Name="Quit"  Click= "Quit_click"/>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Background">
                <MenuItem Header="_Show Background Paper" x:Name="ShowBackgroundPaperMenuItem" IsCheckable="true" IsChecked="True" Click="ShowBackgroundPaperMenuItem_Click"/>
                <MenuItem Header="_Select Background Paper..." x:Name="SelectBackgroundPaper"  Click="SelectBackgroundPaper_Click"/>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Layers">
                <MenuItem Header="_Show Grid" x:Name="ShowGridMenuItem" IsCheckable="true" IsChecked="True" Click="ShowGrid_Click"/>
                <MenuItem Header="_Show Placenames" x:Name="ShowPlacenamesMenuItem" IsCheckable="true" IsChecked="True" Click="ShowPlacenames_Click"/>
                <MenuItem Header="_Show Coordinates" x:Name="ShowCoordinatesMenuItem" IsCheckable="true" IsChecked="False" Click="ShowCoordinatesMenuItem_Click"/>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Help">
                <MenuItem Header="_About the General Staff Map Design Module" x:Name="AboutMenuItem" />

            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>

        <Grid  Height="872">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="284" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1167" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Canvas Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="817"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="273" Name="LeftCanvas">
                <Image  Width="271" Height="817" Stretch="Fill" Name="LeftPanelPaper"  />
                <Label Canvas.Left="6" Canvas.Top="30" Content="Select Drawing Tool:" Height="49" Name="label1" Width="261" FontFamily="Nestor WF" FontSize="26" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" />
                <TextBlock Canvas.Left="46" Canvas.Top="163" Text="Ponds &amp; Lakes" Height="46" Name="PondsLabel" FontSize="40" MouseDown="Pond_MouseDown" MouseMove="Pond_MouseMove" MouseLeave="Pond_MouseLeave"  Foreground="Black" Width="202" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                <Label Canvas.Left="6" Canvas.Top="156" Content="P" Height="57" Name="PondCheckMark" Width="58" FontFamily="Wingdings 2" FontSize="48" Foreground="#FFC44F1C"  />
                <TextBlock Canvas.Left="46" Canvas.Top="94" FontSize="40" Foreground="Black" Height="43" Name="WoodsLabel" Text="Woods " MouseDown="Woods_MouseDown"  MouseMove="Woods_MouseMove" MouseLeave="Woods_MouseLeave" />
                <Label Canvas.Left="3" Canvas.Top="87" Content="P" FontFamily="Wingdings 2" FontSize="48" Foreground="#FFC44F1C" Height="42" Name="WoodsCheckMark" Width="58" />
                <TextBlock Canvas.Left="46" Canvas.Top="233" FontSize="40" Foreground="Black" Height="46" Name="FortLabel" Text="Fortifications" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="202" FontFamily="Rudyard WF" MouseDown="Fort_MouseDown"  MouseMove="Fort_MouseMove" MouseLeave="Fort_MouseLeave"/>
                <Label Canvas.Left="6" Canvas.Top="226" Content="P" FontFamily="Wingdings 2" FontSize="48" Foreground="#FFC44F1C" Height="57" Name="FortCheckMark" Width="58" />
                <TextBlock Canvas.Left="46" Canvas.Top="299" FontFamily="Rudyard WF" FontSize="40" Foreground="Black" Height="46" Name="SwampLabel" Text="Swamp" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="202"  MouseDown="Swamp_MouseDown"  MouseMove="Swamp_MouseMove" MouseLeave="Swamp_MouseLeave"/>
                <Label Canvas.Left="6" Canvas.Top="291" Content="P" FontFamily="Wingdings 2" FontSize="48" Foreground="#FFC44F1C" Height="57" Name="SwampCheckMark" Width="58" />
                <TextBlock Canvas.Left="46" Canvas.Top="368" FontFamily="Rudyard WF" FontSize="40" Foreground="Black" Height="46" Name="HillLabel" Text="Hills &amp; Ridges" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="202" MouseDown="Hill_MouseDown"  MouseMove="Hill_MouseMove" MouseLeave="Hill_MouseLeave"/>
                <Label Canvas.Left="6" Canvas.Top="360" Content="P" FontFamily="Wingdings 2" FontSize="48" Foreground="#FFC44F1C" Height="57" Name="HillCheckMark" Width="58" />
                <TextBlock Canvas.Left="46" Canvas.Top="438" FontFamily="Rudyard WF" FontSize="40" Foreground="Black" Height="46" Name="RoadLabel" Text="Roads" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="202" MouseDown="Road_MouseDown"  MouseMove="Road_MouseMove" MouseLeave="Road_MouseLeave"/>
                <Label Canvas.Left="6" Canvas.Top="430" Content="P" FontFamily="Wingdings 2" FontSize="48" Foreground="#FFC44F1C" Height="57" Name="RoadsCheckMark" Width="58" />
                <TextBlock Canvas.Left="46" Canvas.Top="512" FontFamily="Rudyard WF" FontSize="40" Foreground="Black" Height="46" Name="RiverLabel" Text="Rivers" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="202" MouseDown="River_MouseDown"  MouseMove="River_MouseMove" MouseLeave="River_MouseLeave"/>
                <Label Canvas.Left="3" Canvas.Top="506" Content="P" FontFamily="Wingdings 2" FontSize="48" Foreground="#FFC44F1C" Height="57" Name="RiverCheckMark" Width="58" />
                <TextBlock Canvas.Left="46" Canvas.Top="585" FontFamily="Rudyard WF" FontSize="40" Foreground="Black" Height="46" Name="CityLabel" Text="Cities" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="202" MouseDown="City_MouseDown"  MouseMove="City_MouseMove" MouseLeave="City_MouseLeave"/>
                <TextBlock Canvas.Left="46" Canvas.Top="648" FontFamily="Rudyard WF" FontSize="40" Foreground="Black" Height="46" Name="PlacenameLabel" Text="Placenames" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="202" MouseDown="Placename_MouseDown"  MouseMove="Placename_MouseMove" MouseLeave="Placename_MouseLeave"/>
                <Label Canvas.Left="6" Canvas.Top="579" Content="P" FontFamily="Wingdings 2" FontSize="48" Foreground="#FFC44F1C" Height="57" Name="CityCheckMark" Width="58" />
                <Label Canvas.Left="6" Canvas.Top="641" Content="P" FontFamily="Wingdings 2" FontSize="48" Foreground="#FFC44F1C" Height="57" Name="PlacenamesCheckMark" Width="58" />
                <TextBlock Canvas.Left="46" Canvas.Top="714" FontFamily="Rudyard WF" FontSize="40" Foreground="Black" Height="46" Name="BridgeLabel" Text="Bridges" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="202" MouseDown="Bridge_MouseDown"  MouseMove="Bridge_MouseMove" MouseLeave="Bridge_MouseLeave"/>
                <Label Canvas.Left="6" Canvas.Top="705" Content="P" FontFamily="Wingdings 2" FontSize="48" Foreground="#FFC44F1C" Height="57" Name="BridgeCheckMark" Width="58" />
            </Canvas>

            <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="817"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1183" Name="MainCanvas" Grid.Column="1" MouseDown="Canvas_MouseDown_1" MouseUp="Canvas_MouseUp_1"  MouseMove="Canvas_MouseMove_1">
                <Image Width="1167" Height="817" Stretch="Fill" Name="PaperTextureSource" />
                <Image Width="1167" Height="817"  Name="MapBorderSource" Opacity="60" OpacityMask="{x:Null}" />
            </Canvas>
    </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Does anybody have any idea why all of MainCanvas is not being saved to disk?

---

Edit:
Here's the solution (with the complete method):

```
  private void SaveMapFileAs_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog();
        dlg.DefaultExt = ".bmp"; // Default file extension
        dlg.Filter = "BMP files (.bmp)|*.bmp"; // Filter files by extension

        // Show save file dialog box
        Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

        // Process save file dialog box results
        if (result == true)
        {
            string filename = dlg.FileName;
            RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)MainCanvas.RenderSize.Width,
                  (int)MainCanvas.RenderSize.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Default);

            VisualBrush sourceBrush = new VisualBrush(MainCanvas);
            DrawingVisual drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();
            DrawingContext drawingContext = drawingVisual.RenderOpen();
            using (drawingContext)
            {
                drawingContext.DrawRectangle(sourceBrush, null, new Rect(new Point(0, 0),
                       new Point(MainCanvas.RenderSize.Width, MainCanvas.RenderSize.Height)));
            }

            rtb.Render(drawingVisual);
            //endcode as BMP
            BitmapEncoder bmpEncoder = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
            bmpEncoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(rtb));

            //save to memory stream
            System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

            bmpEncoder.Save(ms);
            ms.Close();
            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filename, ms.ToArray());
        }

    }
```

On a personal note, I would just like to ask, "What's going on with Stackoverflow? It's got so snarky that's almost impossible to ask a question and get an answer these days.

Comment: Not my forte, but Usually it's left, top.  Your code seems to be doing right,bot:  RenderTargetBitmap((int)rect.Right,
                  (int)rect.Bottom, 96d, 96d, System.Windows.Media.PixelFormats.Default);
                rtb.Render(MainCanvas);

Comment: It has to be right and bottom or it throws an error. The code actually came from a Stackoverflow answer

Comment: what error etc?  For me the main issue is you are clearly ending up with a bitmap where the drawn image is not at zero left

Comment: Argument out of range error (o,o). The parameters from RengerTargetBitmap are WIDTH and LENGTH not coordinates.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know, I'm more of a winforms guy, sorry.  That being said the results are exactly the same as I would expect from a drawimage with an incorrect left. Maybe a DPI issue?

Comment: For the sake of readability, you should use `rect.Width` and `rect.Height` instead of `rect.Right` and `rect.Bottom`. Besides readability, the latter ones are only correct if `rect.Left` and `rect.Top` (aka `rect.X` and `rect.Y`) are zero.

Comment: As a note, you should clean up your layout. For the left side menu, use a StackPanel instead of a Canvas with absolute positioning of Labels and TextBlocks. Why Labels at all? Use only TextBlocks. Try to avoid fixed element sizes like the 1167x817 Images. WPF layout is extremely powerful. Try to understand and utilize it.

Comment: Those are certainly great suggestions. But do you have ANY IDEA WHY IT'S NOT SAVING THE MAINCANVAS AREA CORRECTLY?

Answer (score 0):

This is the complete method that works and solves the problem (the original post on Stackoverflow where the original code came from is incorrect):

```
 private void SaveMapFileAs_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog();
            dlg.DefaultExt = ".bmp"; // Default file extension
            dlg.Filter = "BMP files (.bmp)|*.bmp"; // Filter files by extension

            // Show save file dialog box
            Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

            // Process save file dialog box results
            if (result == true)
            {
                string filename = dlg.FileName;
                RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)MainCanvas.RenderSize.Width,
                      (int)MainCanvas.RenderSize.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Default);

                VisualBrush sourceBrush = new VisualBrush(MainCanvas);
                DrawingVisual drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();
                DrawingContext drawingContext = drawingVisual.RenderOpen();
                using (drawingContext)
                {
                    drawingContext.DrawRectangle(sourceBrush, null, new Rect(new Point(0, 0),
                           new Point(MainCanvas.RenderSize.Width, MainCanvas.RenderSize.Height)));
                }

                rtb.Render(drawingVisual);
                //endcode as BMP
                BitmapEncoder bmpEncoder = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
                bmpEncoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(rtb));

                //save to memory stream
                System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

                bmpEncoder.Save(ms);
                ms.Close();
                System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filename, ms.ToArray());
            }

        }
```